# Movie where 3 siblings get lost between universes in a hotel

Tags: story-identification

It is a movie from around the early to last 2000s.

They enter an elevator and press all the buttons, bringing them to another universe. They enter the room with the key the parents gave them, but it has two strangers. The third sibling is still lost in a part that eerily resembles the infamous [backrooms image](https://w4n3g4i6.rocketcdn.me/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/The-Backrooms-.jpg) (yellow walls, seemingly never-ending.)

After a few things I don't remember, a boiler man from the first universe tells them that the elevator was made to punish people, and they get back with the third sibling after following a creature that unwillingly will eat their eyes if they're open.

They enter their room only to see the original third sibling telling her parents, and they realize that the black sandals the third girl was wearing are red on the one they just got back with.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is [*The Many Place*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt10241428/). Not a movie, I might add, but rather an episode of the anthology TV series [*Creeped Out*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt7573024/?ref_=tt_ov_inf).

> Three siblings, on a rainy vacation in Australia, are stuck killing time in the hotel. But the more they explore, the more questions they have. Where does one hallway end and another begin? And what lies behind that next door?

The ending is identical to your description, per [this description of the plot](https://creeped-out.fandom.com/wiki/The_Many_Place)

> The siblings return to the correct reality, indicated by the picture
> in the corridor, which is now upside down once again. Nita asks Max
> how she knew to close her eyes; Max says 'the blind boiler man' told
> her. Nita realises something is wrong, as the boiler man they met was
> not blind. Nita also notices Max, who was wearing black shoes earlier,
> is now wearing red shoes.

Comment: THANK YOU SOOOOO MUCH